# How do I totally remove automatically created hyper links in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

When I create a new email or reply to someone in Gmail. The link string starts with "HTTP" would be automatically turned into a link.

There is a "remove" option but even if I clicked on it. The link will still be there in the sent email.

Is there anyway to totally remove it (so that the link would remain just as a raw string)?

Answer (score 3):

Gmail (and, in fact, most modern email clients) will convert something that looks like an URL into a clickable link.

If you want to prevent that, there are a couple of things you can do:

1. Leave off the protocol; compare:

   - http://www.example.com
   - www.example.com
2. Munge the URL in some way, like leaving off one of the slashes, omitting the colon, or putting a space between the slashes and the server name

   - http:/www.example.com
   - http//www.example.com
   - http:// www.example.com
3. I haven't tried, but by putting a [zero-width space character](https://superuser.com/q/156640/1100) in the URL, a computer will see the character and it won't match what it thinks a URL looks like, but to a person they won't see it

   - ht​tp://www.example.com

Of course, that's not to say your recipient's email client won't fall for these tricks and render a link anyway.

Comment: An alternative to the zero width space (which would permit wrapping in the url-like-text) is the word joiner, U+2060, which is a zero width non-breaking space.